# Javascript Brackets IDE shows errors in JQuery 3.5.1 file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to JS. Doing a course on Udemy. I am using the Brackets IDE. I downloaded JQuery-3.5.1 into my JS folder and I added it as a SRC using the script tag.
I am doing a simple "Hello World" type popup but it is not working.
When I look at the JQuery file in Brackets it shows that there are 63 errors. I simply did a "Save As" of the file when I downloaded it, as it was already a JS file type. Why would all these errors show up?

My main concern is I don't know why my popup alert is not showing. Is it the errors in the JQuery library or is it my code?

My code is here:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $.(document).ready( function() {
        //code goes here
        alert("Welcome to MyPage with JQuery");
    });
</script>
```

Below is the screen capture of the errors in the Bracket IDE:

[image: JQuery errors in Bracket IDE]
Some advice here would be very much appreciated.

---

**Update:**

Just a note on how this was resolved. I eventually looked at the solution code, could not see the issue until I compared it directly with mine as below:

$(document).ready( function() { alert("Welcome To Loso With JQuery!"); });

$.(document).ready( function() { alert("Welcome to MyPage with JQuery"); });

As you can see, mine (which is the second line of code) has an unnecessary full stop as the second character. I did the CSS module yesterday and I think that was a holdover from that. Anyway, that is my story and I am sticking to it. To those who helped out in the comments section, thank you.

Comment: You should be saying you are new to "Brackets" too? What does your dev web server say? What does the browser say actually since this is client-side?

Comment: Yes I am also new to using the IDE. I don't know how to talk to me web server.

Comment: Okay I will go look at the browser. Not used to going through there so it might take a little while.

Comment: Doesn't Brackets have an option for you to "open in browser" or similar?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '(' on line 10 which is the (document).ready line of code

Comment: $.(document).ready( function() {

Comment: Not sure why there is a bracket syntax error there

Comment: `$.(document)` should be `$(document)` (no dot)

Comment: I eventually found it:

Comment: Yes, I found it by comparing my code to the instructors code. I had to put both sections into notepad one above the other, then I could see the lines are a different length. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction GetSet.

Comment: For future reference, you can use `@name` and that user will get a notification, eg @GetSet

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m much appreciated. Is there any way to mark this question as resolved?

Comment: Not without an answer and, in this case, it's a small typo, so the recommendation is to simply leave or delete it.  Glad you got this sorted.